# Comparing property names in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, object, properties

I'm trying to write a function to compare property names, but I'm not sure how to do so. This is what I've tried, and it's not working as intended.

```
function propCompare(objA, objB) {
    // assumes both objects have same length
    for (var prop in objA) {
        if (objB[prop] === undefined)
            return false;
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to obtain is if `objA` has a property that `objB` doesn't have, then don't bother checking further, and just return `false`. If everything matches up, return `true`.

Comment: Objects don't have a length. Also, you should probably be using `Object.keys` to iterate only own properties. Two objects may have the same own properties, but may have different properties in their prototype chain.

Comment: " If everything matches up, return true" - return true; has to be moved behind the loop. Otherwise you're only checking whether the first property of objA matches the first of objB

Comment: So does every property in B need to be in A?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you are returning in the first iteration of the loop. Instead only return if you find a failed match.

Second, use the `in` operator instead of checking for `undefined`.

```
function propCompare(objA, objB) {
    for (var prop in objA) {
        if (!(prop in objB))
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

So now the first time a property is found in `objA` that does not exist in `objB`, the function will return `false` immediately.

Otherwise, it will be allowed to go through the entire loop, and then return `true` at the end, because no properties were not found

---

If you don't want to give consideration to inherited properties, then replace `!(prop in objB)` with `!objB.hasOwnProperty(prop)`.